# SAS Datetime Input reads in the same date for each row

Tags: sql, datetime, sas, format

I am attempting to read in many files of data including a column of datetimes. When I read in all of the files, the datetime column contains the same date everywhere (31 JUL 2015 00:00:00, or in SAS format: 1753920000) even though the data files being read in have many different datetimes in that column.  Why would my code be outputting the same date for every row?

Code:

```
%let type=40;    
%let year=2015;
%let months =07;
%let days = 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31;
%let filetype=.csv;

%macro import_files;

  %do K=1 %to 31; /*day*/
      %let nmbr = %scan(&type,1); 
      %let yr=%scan(&year,1);
      %let mnth=%scan(&months,1);
      %let day=%scan(&days,&K);
      %let exportfile = "C:\Users\Top&nmbr&yr&mnth&day&filetype";
      %let src = "\\2119\outfile";

    /* Import All files in that Alpha, Year and Month Group*/

      DATA work.RAW_DATA;
        INFILE &src firstobs=3 LRECL=1000 DELIMITER=',' MISSOVER DSD;
        INPUT city_cd : $CHAR3.
              shop_car_type_cd : $CHAR4.
              lor: ?? BEST2.
              arv_dt : ?? MMDDYY10.
              shop_dttm : ?? ANYDTDTM19.  /* This is the datetime that reads in the same date for every observation */

      RUN;
  %end;

%mend import_files;

%import_files;
```

CSV datafile:

```
ATL CCAR    1   10:30   9/7/2015    01JUL2015:00:00:00
```

After reading into SAS:

```
ATL CCAR    1   37800   20338   1751500800
```

Comment: Can you show some example values from the file that are not being converted properly by ANYDTDTM informat?  You might need to read it as text and convert it yourself.

Comment: The datetimes that are not converting properly are all in this form: 27JUL2015:00:00:00

Comment: Did you try removing the `??` modifiers so that SAS will print errors to the log?

Comment: I removed them and there were 0 errors and 0 warnings in the log; however, it still outputted the same datetime in all of the observations with the SAS format of one 10 character number like: 1753920000.

Comment: Try to create a data file with just a couple of records that replicates the issue and post the data.   I cannot replicate reading `27JUL2015:00:00:00 ` incorrectly.

Comment: I have provided one line of data in the form it is found in in its original CSV and then in the form that SAS puts it into once being read in. In the smaller dataset, the read in will have different times for different observations but the dates are the exact same even though in their original form there are differing dates in the CSV.

Comment: Your CSV data doesn't look like CSV to me.  Where are the commas?

Comment: You don't need that complicated macro.  You can read all those TOP files with a FILEREF that use a wildcard.  Perhaps Top*.csv

Comment: That reads in fine to me.  It loos like it read okay to your program too, though.  ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something serious, you have 5 variables listed on your INPUT statement but 6 in your sample data. Which one is correct? I would also switch the `MISSOVER` to `TRUNCOVER`, . Additionally consider specifying an `informat` for your variables instead of how you're trying to read it. You're not getting any errors because of the ?? which suppresses any errors. Remove them from your code. I'll post an answer below to help you get started but it's not likely correct.

As mentioned, you also do not have a CSV file unless you copied and pasted from an Excel file, which you shouldn't do. Excel may be adding/stripping something from your data that we can't see which can cause the issues.

```
data have;
informat arv_dt mmddyy10. shop_dttm anydtdtm. time_data time.;
format shop_dttm datetime21. time_data time.;
INPUT
    city_cd           $
    shop_car_type_cd  $
    lor 
    time_data         
    arv_dt        
    shop_dttm;
cards;
ATL CCAR    1   10:30   9/7/2015    01JUL2015:00:00:00
;
run;

proc print data=have;
run;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my problem. With the format and informat lines that you provided, I still get one datetime  July 03, 2015 for every row even though there are many different dates in the files in their original form. Do you know any other solutions?

Comment: You fixed the 5 vs 6 variable issue? Also, post your full code including what format you applied.